# (U.S.A.) Removing senators not from your state

Tags: united-states, congress, us-senate

**Background example:**
People in California want to remove a senator from Kentucky.

Can this be performed?

How can it be performed?

Comment: They move to Kentucky and vote for the other guy. Senators are not removable except by death, resignation or not being elected.

Comment: Does the Kentucky senator need to acknowledge any communications from people of California (such as phone calls, emails, or letters)?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews No. Nor does a Kentucky Senator need to acknowledge any communication from people of Kentucky.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118497/discussion-on-question-by-thomas-matthews-u-s-a-removing-senators-not-from-yo).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way that a member of the House of Representatives, or a U.S. Senator can be removed from office (other than by resignation, death, or expiration of a term of office without being re-elected) is by a two-thirds vote of the chamber removing that member. The relevant provision of the United States Constitution is Article I, Section 5, Clause 2 which states:

> Each House may determine the Rules of its Proceedings, punish its
> Members for disorderly Behaviour, and, with the Concurrence of two
> thirds, expel a Member.

So, a member of the U.S. House of Representatives may be removed by a two-thirds vote of the U.S. House, and a U.S. Senator may be removed by a two-thirds vote of the U.S. Senate.

This has been done [five times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_representatives_expelled,_censured,_or_reprimanded) since 1789 in the U.S. House, most recently in 2002. It has been done [fifteen times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_senators_expelled_or_censured) since 1789 in the U.S. Senate (the most recent 14 times in 1861 and 1862 in connection with the U.S. Civil War).

[The case of William Blount in 1797](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impeachment_in_the_United_States) established the precedent that expulsion of a member by a chamber, rather than impeachment, is the proper process to remove a member of Congress.

Members of Congress [may not be recalled](https://www.everycrsreport.com/reports/RL30016.html), and are not automatically removed from office upon conviction of a crime.

Apart from the expulsion process, there is no way for voters or states to remove U.S. Senators not from their own state, something that doesn't make sense to be possible in the overall context of the structure of the United States government under the U.S. Constitution.

Senate Rule XXIII in part [provides that](https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/CDOC-99sdoc33/html/CDOC-99sdoc33.htm) ``if the impeachment shall
not, upon any of the articles presented, be sustained by the
votes of two-thirds of the members present, a judgment of
acquittal shall be entered;''

A quorum of the full Senate and not just those sworn in for the trial is required.

The Senate rules in the case of an expulsion of a member are analogous.

Comment: Is that 2/3rds of everyone or voting?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- "Rule XXIII in part provides that ``if the impeachment shall 
not, upon any of the articles presented, be sustained by the 
votes of two-thirds of the members present, a judgment of 
acquittal shall be entered;'' https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/CDOC-99sdoc33/html/CDOC-99sdoc33.htm A quorum of the full Senate and not just those sworn in for the trial is required.

Comment: I guess I'm confused how to interpret the legalese then, if "members present" doesn't mean "not the full Senate." If 20 GOP Senators boycotted, could Trump be convicted with 53 yeas, 7 nays and 20 abstentions?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- If 20 Senators boycotted, 54 votes would be required to convict. The number of members present who vote to convict must be at least twice as large as the number of members present who do not vote to convict in any regard. An abstention or "present" vote counts as a "no" vote.

Comment: That all sounds fine until you said abstention are nos? How is abstention different from not being present? Does the Senator literally have to not be in the room?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Absention is declining to vote either yes or not when you are present and is marked as "present" in vote tallies in the U.S. Senate. If you are present and don't vote, you count as a "no". If you are not present, you aren't included in determining who votes. There are details of exactly when you are determined to be present and what qualifies, that are spelled out elsewhere in the Senate rules for multiple purposes, but I couldn't tell you right off hand.